# Rationality and transcendence of zeros of Bessel functions

Tags: bessel-functions, transcendental-numbers, rationality-testing

Is the first zero 2.40482555769577... of the Bessel function $J_0(x)$ transcendental? (Is *anything* known about its status?)

Comment: since you tagged "rationality testing", its at least known to be irrational. (I don't work in number theory, just found it on a google) https://www.researchgate.net/publication/231789615_Legendre_polynomials_in_irrationality_proofs Abstract - It is shown that a simple trick involving Legendre polynomials readily yields the irrationality of ea, , π2, and of the zeros of Bessel functions of integer order. Generalisation of this idea yields the irrationality of ζ(3). There may be hope in a book mentioned in the introduction, where "the trancendence of some of these numbers is proved"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is transcendental since for all non zero $\alpha\in\overline{\mathbb Q}$, $J_0(\alpha)$ is transcendental. It is a result of Siegel (1929)

Original Siegel Paper
Uber einige Anwendungen diophantischer Approximationen

Comment: Legend has it that when Max Born came to Göttingen shortly after 1900, he did not know whether to become a physicist or a mathematician. So he asked Hilbert for advice. Hilbert said "try to find out whether these zeros are transcendent" and after a few months Born gave up and switched to physics.